# How to activate AUCTeX support for beamer without preamble?

Tags: auctex, syntax-highlighting, beamer

Usually, AUCTeX activates beamer-specific settings (e.g. syntax highlighting)   depending on `\documentclass`. In my LaTeX templates, however, I have separated the preamble from the rest of the document using `\input{beamer-preamble}`.

Here's an MWE:

```
\input{beamer-preamble}  % `beamer-preamble.tex` only contains `\documentclass{beamer}`
\begin{document}

\title{Some title}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Some frame title}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

In this example, the argument of `\frametitle` should be highlighted similarly to the argument of `\title`.

How can I tell AUCTeX to still apply the beamer-specific settings?

Comment: Can you show your `beamer-preamble` and a .tex file where you use it and do the actual typesetting?

Comment: @ArashEsbati I've updated the question. Interestingly, AUCTeX sometimes does it right, but not always.

Comment: What is your setting of `Tex-auto-local`?  Have you updated the local files?

Comment: @AndrewSwann `Tex-auto-local` points to some directory under .emacs.d. In fact, when I remove the AUCTeX files there, the highlighting changes for the worse.

Comment: It us usually just "auto" so that information can be stored in that subdirectory where your current tex file is.  Have you changed the defaults?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, I suggest you create a proper class file `beamer-preamble.cls` like this:

```latex
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e} 
\ProvidesClass{beamer-preamble}
  [2017/04/26 v0.1 My Beamer Preamble]
\LoadClass[<beamer-options>]{beamer}
```

Next, you want to have an AUCTeX style file for `beamer-preamble.cls`.  Doing <kbd>M-x TeX-auto-generate RET</kbd> in one way.  But I recommend writing your own style file.  Something like this should suffice:

```lisp
(TeX-add-style-hook
 "beamer-preamble"
 (lambda ()
   (TeX-run-style-hooks "beamer"))
 LaTeX-dialect)
```

Customize `TeX-style-private` to a directory of your choice and save the code above as `beamer-preamble.el` there.  Add this to your init file,

```lisp
(setq TeX-parse-self t)
```

restart Emacs and open your .tex file.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, which brought me to think about an even simpler (but more ad-hoc) solution: just add `eval: (TeX-run-style-hooks "beamer")` to the local variables of the file. Still, I really like the more generic  approach of defining classes and including them globally.